# Fail to get back on the UI Thread using Rx, MVVM Light and Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light, system.reactive

I fail to get back on the UI  thread using Reactive Extentions and the MVVM Light Toolkit.

I got the follow properties on a ViewModel:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Workspace> _workspaces;
    public ObservableCollection<Workspace> Workspaces
    {
        get
        {
            return _workspaces;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_workspaces == value)
                return;

            _workspaces = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("WorkspacesLoaded");

        }
    }

    public bool WorkspacesLoaded
    {
        get
        {
            if (_workspaces != null && _workspaces.Count > 0)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Notice the `RaisePropertyChanged("WorkspacesLoaded");` which never seems to arrive at the UI.

The following code subscribes to a `Subject<Workspace>` and from what I read the `.ObserveOnDispatcher()` should bring me back on the UI Thread.

```
        _workspaceSubscription = _workspaceSource.WorkspaceMutations
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
            .Subscribe(OnNewWorkspaceMutation, OnWorkspaceMutationError);

        _workspaceSource.GetWorkspaces();
```

And this code adds to the `Workspaces` property:

```
    private void OnWorkspaceCreated(Workspace workspace)
    {
       Workspaces.Add(workspace);
    }
```

This is what baffles me: The `Workspaces` collection gets properly populated and the UI binds to it properly. However, when I set a breakpoint on the setter of `Workspaces` it never gets hit so my suspicion is that the Observable stream isn't returned to the UI thread.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you add to the Workspaces collection, you don't actually set the collection property again. If you have used

```
Workspaces = new ObservableCollection<Workspace>();
```

then the setting of the wokrspace property would have been triggered. Now it just uses the value that is already there. If you set a breakpoint in the getter it will be hit.

Comment: You're right! A big mistake of me to assume the setter would get hit. The reason I was confused was because I had the required behavior when I did a .Add in the constructor on the ViewModel but this is because the UI is not yet bound to the property.